# How do edit a status media attachment description?

Tags: mastodon

I have a status id from a previous toot of mine that contains an image. The image doesn't have a description/alt-text. I want to edit the toot to include one.

https://docs.joinmastodon.org/methods/statuses/#edit mentions `media_ids[]`, array of media id strings, but what am I to do with a `media_ids`?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this functionality was added with an update in January but is still undocumented. Here is the related Pull request:
https://github.com/mastodon/mastodon/pull/20878

The `PUT /api/v1/statuses/:id` Endpoint should now also have a `media_attributes` array which has the following attributes:

- `id`: the identifier of the media attachment to be modified
- `description` (optional): the new description
- `thumbnail` (optional): the new thumbnail
- `focus` (optional): the new focus point

Comment: This is what I have done so far, and it isn't working.  

Example status with image. https://masto.nyc/@NancyComics/110679862524646435  

1. I get this status' media attachment's id.  

 id: 110678587795725190, type: image url: https://cdn.masto.nyc/media_attachments/files/110/678/587/795/725/190/original/1d188b6c702518bc.jpeg  
2. I use, https://docs.joinmastodon.org/methods/media/#update. It takes the media id,110678587795725190, and I add the new description. The server returns " 404 Not Found: Record not found"  
It seems like I'm misusing the update api and/or missing a step.